# DNS Resolution Errors on New Active Directory (Server 2012 R2)

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, active-directory

In advance I thank you for any help or advice you can provide as I am fairly new to the concepts and config of Active Directory and related roles like DNS, DHCP etc.

I have recently set up a domain controller - DCSERVER - with AD, DNS, DHCP and WSUS roles installed, following the instructions of some simple tutorials available out there on the net.

I have disabled DHCP on my router, and from what I can see, my DHCP setup is working just fine. DCSERVER DHCP gives out dynamic leases from 10.0.0.100-200 which is more than enough for the limited number of devices we have on this fairly small network.

DCSERVER is located at 10.0.0.2, and the Draytek Vigor 2710 (router) is located at 10.0.0.1. It is probably worth mentioning that the below errors are happening more frequently on devices that are not part of the domain but are using the network. That said, it still happens to domain-joined computers.

The DNS server seems to be doing its job most of the time, but every now and then (roughly every half hour of constant browsing) we run into some kind of issue with bad resolution. The most common one is `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`, but often we get other similar DNS errors. We also sometimes get the page to load fine, but scripts / images do not load and thus we end up looking at a broken website. Screenshots below of examples: (Sorry I can't embed them, lack of reputation)

NXDOMAIN Error:

[image]

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED:

[image]

Content Not Loading:

[image]

[image]

I have configured the DNS server to use Google and OpenDNS DNS solutions as forwarders. I have tried just about every one of the tasks one can run on the DNS and DHCP servers including clear cache, scavenge stale resources, start stop restart etc. but to no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated. If there are some kind of reports that I can pull out of Windows Server that helps identify I will happily provide what is needed.

Comment: We're experiencing the same with a Vigor 2920n and I've tried Larryc's answer, to no avail. Is your Draytek your modern, or are you using it in between your ISP modem/router and your DC? We've had to do this to separate the wireless - the Draytek is quite good for this.

Comment: The Draytek is our modem, we're on ADSL2+ here in Aus. I'm not super savvy with the Vigor control panel but I went through it and did my best to make sure its not interfering with DNS or DHCP. It refers to the domain controller for DNS, which then forwards to Google / OpenDNS. I'm working on figuring out how to route DNS through my ISP before hitting the other forwarders based on Larry's suggestion

Comment: Better idea, I'm going to add a tonne of forwarders from the below list and see how that turns out.
http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/free-public-dns-servers.htm

Comment: Also make sure you're pointing the clients to the default gateway as this may also have an affect...

Comment: Clients are directed to the router at 10.0.0.1 as default gateway :)

Answer (score 1):

Your links return "page not found" for me.

My first thought was forwarders and then you answered that for me.
Google's DNS servers are busy, *very* busy. So I would expect an occasional
failure when using them.
Your upstream provider(ISP) should provide your DNS requests. Set your DNS
server to query itself first, and if/when that fails forward the request to 
your upstream provider.

Comment: Thanks Larry! Strange that the links dont work, I did my best to get to 10 rep so I could embed them, but someone downvoted this thread whilst I was doing that :(

Thanks for the input. The DNS server by default queries itself, I cannot add itself to its own list of forwarders if that's what you mean.

Comment: When you configure the network interface on the DNS server tell it to use it's own address as the first DNS server, but don't use localhost. i.e. if the DNS server(DCSERVER) has an IP address of 10.0.0.2 then put 10.0.0.2 as the first DNS server in its network card configuration (don't use 127.0.0.1).

Comment: with the interface set to point to itself, go to the "forwarders" page in DNS and put in the addresses of the two DNS servers that your ISP provides. With this in place, when a DNS request comes in it will look in its own tables to see if it a local machine, if not it will go to the forwarders(your ISP's DNS servers) and ask them to look it up.  There is another method you could employ using root hints, but we don't need to go that route at this time.

Comment: I did already have the DC NIC set to use 10.0.0.2 (itself) as the first preferred DNS server, but also had 10.0.0.1 (the router) set as the secondary based on the AD setup tutorial I watched.

The router was configured to use 10.0.0.2 as primary and 8.8.8.8 as secondary. So I'm not totally sure but it seems like this might have had a bit to do with it...

I'll try removing the router from the alternate DNS server and just leave that blank so that it goes straight to forwarders instead of hitting the router if it cant find a record on itself. Hopefully this will help.